# jQuery fadeOut, but no fadeIn anymore?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I tried something like this:

```
someObject.fadeOut(500, function() {someObject.fadeIn();});
```

I expected the object to fade out and then to reappear. It doesn't. It fades out and it never comes back. I found a workaround which looks like this:

```
someObject.fadeOut(500, function() {someObject.show(); someObject.fadeTo(0, 0); someObject.fadeTo(500,1); });
```

But that feels really awkward. What would be 'best practice' to fade an element out and (later) in again?

EDIT: OK, I tried around the problem somewhat more. The element I am fading is an SVG group in an inline SVG. If I hide a nomal HTML element, then everything works fine. So I guess the problem is connected to that. The svg.jquery extension I use? General problems with SVG and jQuery?

Comment: your syntax works fine for me:   http://jsfiddle.net/FCxAm/

Comment: Your first example works fine for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/HH5EH/

Comment: he have some other issue with CSS or other JS call somewhere...the first line should work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to fade an SVG element. jQuery does not behave equivalently on SVG elements as on html elements as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is happening? I tried this out, and it seems to be behaving as it should.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#clickme').click(function() {
          $('#book').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('#book').fadeIn(500);
          });
        });
    });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1 id="book">this is book tag</h1>
    <button id="clickme">button here</button>
 </body>
</html>
```